# How do I update const array in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Dear team members,

I am new to angular.

I have a ts file.

```
export const HEROES: Hero[] = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Dr Nice' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
];


updateHero(hero:Hero) : void{
  let updateItem = this.heroes.find(x=> x.id == hero.id);

  let index = this.heroes.indexOf(updateItem);

  this.heroes[index] = hero;
}
```

How can I update HEROES file ?

my goal is to select a hero, edit the name and then update the const file. I know it should come from the server. but for playing around ?

Thanks.

Comment: use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to get the index and update that index's value

Comment: for example id the index is 11 and name is Dr Ugly can my end result in the file like this export const HEROES: Hero[] = [
      { id: 11, name: 'Dr  Ugly' },
      { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
      { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
      { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
      { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
      { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
      { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
      { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
      { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
      { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
    ];     Note this class in sperate ts file imported in the component

Comment: @CodeManiac  any chance

Answer (score -1):

you can not assign/update value in the const once it declared. so you need to change the const type to another type.

by default javascript const behavior
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_const.asp

Comment: This is absolutely false. You can't reassign the `const`. You absolutely can mutate the object it refers to. Also, don't site w3schools, it's a repository of junk